# How to get the numeric group owner of a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, ownership

For a bash script,
I need to find the numeric group ID from the file ownership attributes, similar to the output of `ls -nl`, but **only the number**.
If possible, I would like to avoid big parsing magic ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- To determine only the "numerical group ID":

  ```
  stat -c %g /path/to/file/or/directory
  ```
- To determine only the "numerical user ID":

  ```
  stat -c %u /path/to/file/or/directory
  ```